# Insert text within a string in Java 8

Tags: string, java-8

I have a `Map<String, List<highlightData>>` as follows:

```
{def_cd=[HighlightData(text=SOMECODE4, sections=[HighlightData.Section(startOffset=3, endOffset=4), HighlightData.Section(startOffset=7, endOffset=8)])]}
```

here `key` is  `def_cd` and the `value` is `List<HighlightData>`.

`HighlightData` has `text` and `List<Section>` as attributes.

I want to convert the text `SOMECODE4` TO `SOM<highlight>E</highlight>COD<highlight>E</highlight>4`

The position of `<highlight>` and `</highlight>` depends on the `startOffset` and `endOffset`.

`HighlightData` classs is follows:

```
 public final class HighlightData {
    public final static class Section {
        private final int startOffset;
        private final int endOffset;

        public Section(int startOffset, int endOffset) {
            this.startOffset = startOffset;
            this.endOffset = endOffset;
        }

        public int getStartOffset() {
            return startOffset;
        }

        public int getEndOffset() {
            return endOffset;
        }
    }

    private String text;

    private List<Section> sections;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public List<Section> getSections() {
        return sections;
    }

    public void setSections(List<Section> intervals) {
        this.sections = intervals;
    }

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm a bit lost on the applicability of the Map itself, but this is fairly straightforward. You literally retrieve the `List<highlightData>`, and divide the `text` into substrings accordingly (wrapping the substringed sections with the highlight tags). Overall it really seems like a strange design with potentially better approaches

Comment: Maybe post the code with which you build the map you copied the string representation of, you'll get higher chances someone will help you. Making people parsing some random string representation to rebuild your test data lowers your chances getting a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The relevance of the `Map` is unclear. If the key is supposed to be the specified constant, the canonical way to retrieve the mapped value is calling `get` on the map and the existence of the map isn’t worth being mentioned in the question at all.

The value needs clarification too. Apparently, each `HighlightData` has a reference text to be matched against, but you didn’t specify whether there can be multiple matches. If there can be only one match, it would be much more natural, to have a map that associates the text to a list of `Section`s. With your current list, you have to iterate it linearly to find the match.

Constructing the result string is trivial, if you don’t insist on finding a solution that (over)utilizes Java 8 features:

```
String text = "SOMECODE4";
for(HighlightData h: map.get("def_cd")) {
    if(h.getText().equals(text)) {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        int lastPos=0;
        for(HighlightData.Section s: h.getSections()) {
            sb.append(text, lastPos, s.getStartOffset())
              .append("<highlight>")
              .append(text, s.getStartOffset(), lastPos=s.getEndOffset())
              .append("</highlight>");
        }
        text=sb.append(text, lastPos, text.length()).toString();
        break; // remove, if multiple matches are possible
    }
}
```

This code assumes that the list of `HighlightData.Section`s is sorted by position and has no overlapping areas. Note that this code minimizes the copying operations, i.e. does not call `substring` and only appends to the end of the `StringBuilder`, so the result content is created in a single pass. You could improve the performance slightly further by specifying an initial capacity for the `StringBuilder`, which would be
`text.length() + "<highlight></highlight>".length()*h.getSections().size()`…